# Update XML with C# using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

MY XML FILE STRUCTURE

```
<items>
  <item>
    <itemID>1</itemID>
    <isGadget>True</isGadget>
    <name>Star Wars Figures</name>
    <text1>LukeSkywalker</text1>
  </item>
</items>
```

TO READ DATA FROM XML BY ITEMID

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("data.xml"));
var items = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
            where item.Element("itemID").Value == itemID
            select new
            {
                itemID = item.Element("itemID").Value,
                isGadget = bool.Parse(item.Element("isGadget").Value),
                name = item.Element("name").Value,
                text1 = item.Element("text1").Value,
             }

foreach (var item in items)
{
     ....
}
```

How to update XML data by itemID?
Thanks!

Comment: I dont understand why theses LINQ-to-XML questions are so pervasive at the moment. The answers are _right here_. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx

Answer (score 19):

To update your xml use [SetElementValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setelementvalue.aspx) method of the XElement :

```
var items = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
    where item.Element("itemID").Value == itemID
    select item;

foreach (XElement itemElement in items)
{
    itemElement.SetElementValue("name", "Lord of the Rings Figures");
}
```

**EDIT :** Yes, I tried your example and it saves updated data to the file. Save your updated xml with [Save method of the XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830.aspx), here is the code that I tried :

```
string xml = @"<items>
           <item>
            <itemID>1</itemID>
            <isGadget>True</isGadget>
            <name>Star Wars Figures</name>
            <text1>LukeSkywalker</text1>
           </item>
        </items>";

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var items = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
            where item.Element("itemID").Value == "1"
            select item;

foreach (XElement itemElement in items)
{
    itemElement.SetElementValue("name", "Lord of the Rings Figures");
}

xmlDoc.Save("data.xml");
```

Comment: Not working.  Maybe I'm missing something.  Do I have to add xmlDoc.Save("data.xml")?   Even with xmlDoc.Save, it still does not update.

Comment: Canavar, I was hoping to update the xml file directly instead of having to convert it into a string first. thanks!

Answer (score 9):

To update your xml use element method method of the XElement :

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("data.xml"));
var items = (from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
            where item.Element("itemID").Value == itemID
            select item).ToList();
         foreach (var item in items)
         {
                item.Element("itemID").Value=NewValue;
                bool.Parse(item.Element("isGadget").Value)=Newvalue;
                item.Element("name").Value=Newvalue;
                item.Element("text1").Value=Newvalue;
         }
xmlDoc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("data.xml"));
```

or

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("data.xml"));
             foreach (var item in (from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
                where item.Element("itemID").Value == itemID
                select item).ToList())
             {
                    item.Element("itemID").Value=NewValue;
                    bool.Parse(item.Element("isGadget").Value)=Newvalue;
                    item.Element("name").Value=Newvalue;
                    item.Element("text1").Value=Newvalue;
             }
    xmlDoc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("data.xml"));
```

you get information form dynamic and update those changes in button click event means, first you checks the Page load following code is present

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) { .... }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your query is projecting to an anonymous type. If you want to just modify the elements themselves, you want something like:

```
var items = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
            where item.Element("itemID").Value == itemID
            select item;
```

Otherwise known as:

```
var items = xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
                  .Where(item => item.Element("itemID").Value == itemID);
```

I suggest you call `ToList()` as well, so that the whole query is performed and the results stored in a list before you start modifying things:

```
var items = xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
                  .Where(item => item.Element("itemID").Value == itemID)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of call toList() to update xml? Do I need to use the foreach loop to setElementValue?

Comment: Calling ToList() doesn't update the XML, and yes, you'd need to use `foreach`. You haven't said how you want to update the XML though, so it's somewhat tricky to give an example.

Comment: Not sure what are the options for updating a XML document.  Maybe you can suggest the most efficient method. :)

Comment: Can we really recommend calls to ToList? I've seen junior developers get it into their heads that you need a ToList or ToArray after every single query regardless of usage. It seems to me there should be better usage guidelines. This is after all, the gateway to using List<T>.ForEach(). Grim!