# Query for all elements of a specific name with XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML name Sample.xml which I am trying to query accountNo with XDocument:

```
<Request xmlns="http://CompanyName.AppName.version1">
    <Person>
        <AccountNo>83838</AccountNo>
        <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
        <LastName>Jackson</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <AccountNo>789875</AccountNo>
        <FirstName>Chris</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Person>
```

Using below code in C# i am able to fetch Account no of first person

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Sample.xml");    
XNamespace nsSys = "http://CompanyName.AppName.version1";
XElement xEl2 = xmlDoc.Element(nsSys + "Request ");
XElement xEl3 = xEl2.Element(nsSys + "Person");
XElement xEl4 = xEl3.Element(nsSys + "AccountNo");
String sValue = xEl4.Value;
```

**Ouput : 83838**

How do you write code to extract account no of all person
eg.

```
83838

789875
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply project the data using [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):-

```
XNamespace ns = "http://CompanyName.AppName.version1";
var AccountNumbers = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Person")
                         .Select(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "AccountNo")).ToList();
```

This will give you all the AccountNumbers as `List<String>`.

Comment: Hi rahul last question how to modify the AccountNo value ?

Comment: @alicetoppo - You can use `SetElementValue` method, you need to fetch the particular XElement and apply this method. Finally save your Xdocument object. Please refer this answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/1487764/1529657