# Read xml file containing multiple tags with same attribute name and replace the value based on user's input

Tags: c#

Below is my sample XML file stored in the server ;

```
<exam>
  <name>Maths</name>
  <percentage>100</percentage>
</exam>
<exam>
  <name>Physics</name>
  <percentage>70</percentage>
</exam>
<exam>
  <name>Chemistry</name>
  <percentage>70</percentage>
</exam>
```

I have another table as mentioned below

```
Name of Exam                            Percentage
Maths                                       50
Physics                                     60
Chemistry                                   70
```

What I need here is that I need to read this XML File and replace the percentage value in the XML file based on the table that I have. I have more than 75 tags for exam

I have used the below logic of hardcoding everything but I am not sure if my logic would be good

```
    public static void Changepercentage()
    {
        try{

            string xmlpercentage= Loaddefault.xmlpercentage;

            string f = xml
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            // 2
            // Use using StreamReader for disposing.
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                // 3
                // Use while != null pattern for loop
                string line;

                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(line, "<exam>Maths</exam>"))
                    {
                        lines.Add(@"" + line + "");
                        line = "<percentage>50</percentage>";
                    }                       
                }
            }


            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(xmlpercentage, lines.ToArray());

            Logger.Instance.InfoLog("Successfully updated the percentage.xml file");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.Instance.ErrorLog("Problem in updating the percentage.xml file :"+ ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("Problem in updating the percentage.xml file");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Okay, so how far have you got? I would suggest using LINQ to XML for all of this - it's a very pleasant XML API. What is the format of your table? Is it a text file, or in a database, or something else? Do you already have code to work with that? Basically, you've asked a fairly broad question at the moment with no indication of what you've tried or what *specific* problem you've got.

Comment: I have code to read the data from that table. I need logic only to read the XML file and replace the percentage values.

Comment: I have updated what I have got but I am not sure if that is the right way to proceed.

Comment: No, it absolutely isn't. You're trying to manipulate XML, so use an XML API as I said in the first comment.

Comment: This answer link will be also useful.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1487764/1660178

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301233)

```
//Make sure that the project references the System.Xml namespace.
//Use the Imports statement on the Xml namespace

using System.Xml;

//Create a new XmlDocument class, and use the Load method to load it.

XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.Load ("test.xml");

//Iterate through the children of the document element, and find all the "percentage" nodes. and update it.

foreach(XmlNode node1 in node.ChildNodes)
   foreach (XmlNode node2 in node1.ChildNodes)
      if (node2.Name == "percentage")
         {
            Decimal percentage = 60;//your new percentage
            node2.InnerText = percentage;
          }

//Use the Save method of the XmlDocument class to save the altered XML to a new file that is named test1.xml.         

myXmlDocument.Save("test1.xml");
```

Comment: This is *much* more convoluted than the equivalent LINQ to XML would be.

Comment: I think it is much basic implementation. And that article has been archived...but it will be works

Comment: Yes, it will work - but why provide a complex approach when there are simpler ones with more modern APIs? Would you give an answer using `ArrayList` rather than `List<T>`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes you are absolutely right...I have no argument to you...I am fan of you.You are my role model for the programming.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all `<exam>` nodes of your XML, read the child node `<name>`. With the InnerText of name query the data base and put the data base result into the `<percentage>` node.

Something like this should do:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(yourXml);
foreach(XElement exam in doc.Descendants("exam"))
{
    var examName = exam.Descendants("name").First().Value;
    var newPercentage = GetPercentage(examName);
    exam.Descendants("percentage").First().Value = newPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Note that a simpler way of getting the first child element with a particular name is to just use `Element("foo")`. I'd also use the explicit conversions, e.g. `var examName = (string) exam.Element("name");`