# Linq XML to Object, where xml nodes have nested elements

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

I need to generate a `List<Event>` from a XML document, and the `Event` has a `List<Contact>`. How can I convert the XML to a `List<Event>` object when reading:

This is my event class:

```
public class Event
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Contact class

```
public class Contact
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I save the XML document when the user adds something.

```
<Event>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>AA</title>
    <start>2019-12-01T14:13:58.863</start>
    <end>2019-12-01T15:13:58.787</end>
    <contacts>

      <contact>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>ABC</name>
      </contact>

      <contact>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>ABCD</name>
      </contact>

      <contact>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>ABCDE</name>
      </contact>

    </contacts>
  </Event>
```

To get the XML document I use

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument();
xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
```

I'm struck on how to read the items to a list. How can I do it?

Comment: You can deserialize the xml: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the root of your xml is called Events:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Events>
    <Event>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>AA</title>
        <start>2019-12-01T14:13:58.863</start>
        <end>2019-12-01T15:13:58.787</end>
        <contacts>
            <contact>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>ABC</name>
            </contact>
            <contact>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>ABCD</name>
            </contact>
            <contact>
                <id>3</id>
                <name>ABCDE</name>
            </contact>
        </contacts>
    </Event>
    <Event>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>AA</title>
        <start>2019-12-02T14:13:58.863</start>
        <end>2019-12-02T15:13:58.787</end>
        <contacts>
            <contact>
                <id>4</id>
                <name>DEF</name>
            </contact>
            <contact>
                <id>5</id>
                <name>BNH</name>
            </contact>
            <contact>
                <id>6</id>
                <name>KLK</name>
            </contact>
        </contacts>
    </Event>
</Events>
```

You could define the following two classes that would represent the structure of your XML document:

```
[XmlType("Event")]
public class Event
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("start")]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("end")]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("contacts")]
    public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("contact")]
public class Contact
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could deserialize your XML as below:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Event>), new XmlRootAttribute("Events"));
    return (List<Event>) deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

You have to replace the `filename` with the path in which your xml file resides in.

If we assume that you have selected your xml to be copied to the output directory - right click on file and check it's properties to check this or to set it -, then you can get it's path fairly easily as below (assuming that it is called events.xml):

```
var outputDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var filename = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, @"events.xml");
```

In order you get in grips with XmlSerializer, I would suggest you start from [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/) and continue with this [Examples of XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization).

Comment: Hi, this worked, and thanks for the links I'll check those out, I'm new to c# and everything seems totally strange.

Comment: Can i use the same to get a specific node from the xml file and update and save it

Comment: @mikeoconner You are very welcome. I am glad that I helped.

Comment: @mikeoconner Had I have to get a specific node, update it and save it, I would have gone with LINQ to XML. You could start by reading about it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview. And then look answers like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487653/update-xml-with-c-sharp-using-linq or check for tutorials, they are plenty of them. If you need any specific help. Please ask another question stating specifically what's the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Xml.Serialization` to save/load the `Event` object to/from XML. The format of the XML that will be created is very similar to yours.

Saving/loading a `List<Event>` can be done in the same way (in the exmapls below, `Event` needs to be replaced with `List<Event>`).

**Note:** The load (using `XmlSerializer.Deserialize`) in the below example will not work properly with the XML file you created, it works only with an XML file created by the save example (using `XmlSerializer.Serialize`). To use `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` with your own XML file will require adding `XmlElement` attributes to the class properties and providing an `XmlRootAttribute` to the `XmlSerializer` (as in [Christos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913124/christos) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125239/10927863)). If you can create the XML file with `XmlSerializer.Serialize` and not use the file you already created you will save yourself extra work.

Example of saving the `Event` object to XML (serializing):

```
public static void Save(string fileName, Event e)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Event));

    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, e);
    }
}
```

Example of loading the `Event` object from XML (desalinizing):

```
public static Event Load(string fileName)
{
    Event e = null;
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Event));

    using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,  FileShare.None))
    {

        e = (Event)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    return e;
}
```

The XML that will be created for an `Event` object similar (or identical) to what you have in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Event xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <id>1</id>
  <title>AA</title>
  <Start>2019-12-01T14:13:58.863</Start>
  <End>2019-12-01T15:13:58.787</End>
  <contacts>
    <Contact>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>ABCD</Name>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <Name>ABCDE</Name>
    </Contact>
  </contacts>
</Event>
```

Comment: I tried this method, first time it gave me a error saying that the RootTag was not expected. then I found an answer on stackoverflow saying to initialize the serializer like XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<UserEvent>),xRoot);

Comment: Once I did that the code was executed but the List<Events> was empty

Comment: The default operation of `xmlSerializer.Deserialize` will not work correctly with your file. What I meant in the answer is to suggest you to create the XML files with the `XmlSerializer.Serialize` in the first place, this way your object will be serialized to an XML in the default way and `xmlSerializer.Deserialize` will work correctly.
If you want to work with the file you already created, you will have to use `XmlElement` attributes like in [Christos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913124/christos) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59125239/10927863)

Comment: And you will need to provide the `XmlRootAttribute` like in [Christos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913124/christos) answer. If you create the file in the first place with `XmlSerializer.Serialize` than you will have less work, no need for `XmlElement` attributes and `XmlRootAttribute`.